# What's wrong with my Google heatmap data array?

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, heatmap

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span12">
          <div id="map" style="height: 550px"></div>
      </div>
</div>
</div> <script type="text/javascript"   src="http://gmaps-utility-gis.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/fusiontips/src/fusiontips_compiled.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places,visualization&sensor=true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
$('#crime').addClass('active');
get_vehcile_theft_archive();
};

var heat =[];

function get_vehcile_theft_archive(){
$.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo URL;?>police_vehicletheft/get_vehcile_theft_archive',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        for (var i in data){
            heat[i]=new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].latitude,    data[i].longitude);
        }
        console.log(heat);

    }           
});
}

 var center_guwahati =  new google.maps.LatLng(26.171523,91.756096);
 var map;
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


function initialize() {
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 12,
  center: center_guwahati,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  zoomControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
   },
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),myOptions);


var style = [
            {
              "stylers": [
                { "visibility": "simplified" },
                { "saturation": -100 },
                { "gamma": 0.77 }
              ]
            }

           ];
           var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(style, {
             map: map,
             name: 'stylers'
           });    
           map.mapTypes.set('map-style', styledMapType);
           map.setMapTypeId('map-style');

  console.log(heat);  
  var heatMapData = heat;   

  var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
 data: heatMapData
 });
 heatmap.setMap(map);
 }
```

What is wrong with the heatMapData  variable ? why it not get all the values ? the above ajax function getting the values from mysql and i set that to the global variable but i am not getting that data in the heatmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response of `$.ajax` is not available when you call `initialize`, `heat` will still be empty when you create the `heatmap` .

You better call `get_vehcile_theft_archive` `onload` and `initialize` in the `success`-callback of `$.ajax`